# Invalid handle error in thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I keep getting "Thread error: The handle is invalid (6)" when I attempt to use this thread but I can't see the problem.  Please help if you can, thanks!

stackoverlow is complaining that I didn't explain this enough.  So, I created a thread class which compiles without any errors but when I invoke it with execute it seems to run ok but throws this error in the destructor.

```
  tdownloadthread = class(tthread)
    private
      furl,
      ffilename,
      fmsg: string;
      fdl: tidhttp;
      readings,bpstotal,avgbps: int64;
      fpercent: word;
      fsuccess,fcanceled: boolean;
      start: tdatetime;
      fspeed,fremaining: string;
    public
      constructor create(url,filename: string);
      destructor destroy; override;
      procedure execute; override;
      procedure DlWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
      procedure cancel;

      property success: boolean read fsuccess;
      property canceled: boolean read fcanceled;
      property speed: string read fspeed;
      property percent: word read fpercent;
      property remaining: string read fremaining;
      property msg: string read fmsg;
  end;


constructor tdownloadthread.create(url,filename: string);
begin
  fsuccess:=false;
  fcanceled:=false;

  fdl:=tidhttp.Create(nil);
  fdl.OnWork:=dlwork;
  fdl.HandleRedirects:=true;

  furl:=url;
  ffilename:=filename;

  freeonterminate:=false;
end;

destructor tdownloadthread.Destroy;
begin
  fdl.Free;
end;

procedure tdownloadthread.cancel;
begin
  fdl.Disconnect;
  fcanceled:=true;
end;

procedure tdownloadthread.DlWork(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode; AWorkCount: Int64);
var
  Http: TIdHTTP;
  ContentLength: Int64;
  i,h,m,esec,sec,rsec,bps: Integer;
  f: tdatetime;
begin
  Http := TIdHTTP(ASender);
  ContentLength := Http.Response.ContentLength;

  if (Pos('chunked', LowerCase(Http.Response.ResponseText)) = 0) and
     (ContentLength > 0) then
  begin
    fpercent := trunc(100*(AWorkCount / ContentLength));

    esec := secondsbetween(now, start);

    if (avgbps > 0) then
     begin
       i:=contentlength div avgbps;
       f:=incsecond(now, i);
       rsec:=secondsbetween(now, f);

       sec:=rsec - esec;

       h:=sec div 3600;
       m:=sec div 60 - H * 60;
       sec:=sec - (H * 3600 + M * 60) ;
    end;

    if (esec > 0) then
      bps:=(aworkcount div esec)
       else
      bps:=0;

    inc(readings);
    inc(bpstotal, bps);
    avgbps:=bpstotal div readings;

    if (avgbps / 1024 < 1024) then
      fspeed:=format('%2f KB/s', [avgbps / 1024])
       else
      fspeed:=format('%2f MB/s', [(avgbps div 1024) / 1024]);

    fremaining:=format('%s m %s s', [zero(m), zero(secno)]);
  end;
end;

procedure tdownloadthread.Execute;
var fn,cd: string;
    data: tmemorystream;
begin
  try
    start:=now;

    data:=tmemorystream.Create;

    fdl.Get(furl, data);
    cd:=fdl.Response.ContentDisposition;
    if (pos('filename=', cd) > 0) then
      fn:=extractfilepath(paramstr(0))+copy(cd, pos('=', cd)+1, length(cd))
         else
      fn:=ffilename;
    data.SaveToFile(fn);
    ffilename:=fn;
    fsuccess:=true;

    data.Free;
  except
    on e: exception do
      begin
        fsuccess:=false;
        fmsg:=e.Message;
      end;
  end;
end;

procedure testdownload;
var downloadthread: tdownloadthread;
begin
  downloadthread:=tdownloadthread.create('http://www.someurl.com/filename.old',extractfilepath(paramstr(0))+'filename.new');
  downloadthread.Execute;
  if downloadthread.canceled then showmessage('canceled');
  if downloadthread.success then showmessage('success');
  if not downloadthread.success then showmessage('error: '+downloadthread.msg);
  downloadthread.Free;
end;
```

Comment: You should not call the thread execute method from the main thread (or at all BTW).  Freeing the thread in the same procedure without proper synchronization will end the thread before it's started.

Comment: Yeah - I missed the call to execute() and the inappropriate free.  I didn't get that far:)

Comment: @MartinJames, add that to your answer, you spotted the missing `Inherited` after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to call the inherited ctor for TThread:

```
constructor tdownloadthread.create(url,filename: string);
begin
  inherited create(true); // construct TThread
  fsuccess:=false;
  fcanceled:=false;

  fdl:=tidhttp.Create(nil);
  fdl.OnWork:=dlwork;
  fdl.HandleRedirects:=true;

  furl:=url;
  ffilename:=filename;

  freeonterminate:=false;
  resume; // actually run thread
end;
```

Also, as poinnted out by @LU RD, there is no need to directly call the Execute() method of the TThread instance - the thread is given execution directly by the OS.

As for freeing it, there are some choices.  In order of preference:

1) Don't free it at all.  If you intend to make more than one download during your app run, loop the thread round a producer-consumer queue pop, so that the thread can be re-used to download more files without the misery of trying to free it at all.

2) Let the thread instance free itself, (freeOnTerminate=true) after freeing its internal resources, (eg. the TidHTTP instance), in a try/finally.

-999999)  Use an OnTerminate handler or any of the other horrible Delphi TThread stuff like TThread.WaitFor.

Comment: TThread.Resume is deprecated. You can just do "inherited create(false)" and then there is no need to call Resume (the TThread it's going to wait until all the code in Create is executed before starting the thread anyway).